# How to make this into a nested list?

Tags: python

```py
def inputs():
    taxrate = 0.05 
    name = "Your Mom"
    Item = input("What is the name of the item?")
    Price = float(input("What is the price of the item?"))
    Numberofitems = int(input("How much of the item?"))
    information_list = {}
    information_list[Item] = name, Item, Price, Numberofitems, taxrate
    sentry = "y"
    while sentry == "y":
        taxrate = 0.05
        name = "Your mom"
        Item = input("What is the name of the item?")
        Price = float(input("What is the price of the item?"))
        Numberofitems = int(input("How much of the item?"))
        information_list = {}
```

So this my code. Currently I have the data in dictionary form; I want to make it into a nested list, but have no idea how to. The idea is that the user inputs information about an item they want, I ask them the price, quantity, etc. The goal is to run the program for as many inputs the user has and to put everything into a nested list to use later for calculations like the subtotal of all items.

```
information_list[Item] = [name, Item, Price, Numberofitems, taxrate]
sentry = input("Would you like to run the program again (y #or n)?")
print(information_list)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are expecting for the "nested list"?

Comment: yeah sure. Like [[Car, $20000, 40], [Bike, $4000, 54]]

Comment: yeah sure [[Car, $40000, 54], [Biike,$500,54]]

Comment: So, you already have the data like ```information_list = {key1: [Car, $40000, 54], key2: [Biike,$500,54]} ``` (this is what I understand by dictionary form). If that is the case, you can just do a list comprehension like ```list_comp = [information_list[key] for key in information_list] ``` . Please, let me know if that is the case.